# Which external DAC can be used with STM32F7?

Tags: stm32, dac

Problem Statement: I'm developing hardware for piezo scan for which I need analog output in form of ramp signal which will be feed to piezo. Piezo operating range is between 0 to 30V. So I will generate 0 to 3.3V from STM32 uC and after then I'm planning to amplify the signal. Earlier, I used internal DAC of STM32 but however, it get damaged and also signal after amplification doesn't look like ramp when seen through oscilloscope.

Conclusion: What I have concluded that I might be due to some back reflection from circuitry as I am pretty sure it is not due to mishandling of microcontroller.
Thus, I think using an external DAC will give a precise output and more reliable.

Also, suggest such DAC which is easy to program

Comment: Please add the schematic showing your full setup.

Comment: If the internal DAC output got damaged, your circuit will likely damage the external DAC output too. You need to fix your amplifier input, not an external DAC.

Comment: You appear to be chasing down the wrong solution and not concentrating on fixing your original issue.